# How to add a gradient above button in SwiftUI that is overlapping the content? iOS 13

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, gradient

I have to add a gradient over the button that is showing transparency over the text above the button. The height of the button should be 60. The height of gradient should be 30, but the gradient should overlap other content in the view. Unfortunately I have to support iOS 13. [image]

What I have currently is displaying the gradient over the button, but the total height of the button is 60 + 30:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {
           Rectangle()
               .foregroundColor(.clear)
               .background(
                   LinearGradient(
                       gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white.opacity(0.1), .white.opacity(1)]),
                       startPoint: .top,
                       endPoint: .bottom))
               .frame(height: 30)

           Button(action: {
               state.isExpanded.toggle()
           }, label: {
               Text(state.isExpanded ? "Collapse" : "Expand")
                   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                          minHeight: 60,
                          maxHeight: 60,
                          alignment: .center)
                   .foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                   .background(Color(.white))
           })
               .buttonStyle(.plain)
       }
```

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I am thinking that you can use an overlay on the view above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps someone, I managed to do it with overlay.

```swift
   Button(action: {
             state.isExpanded.toggle()
          }, label: {
             Text(state.isExpanded ? "Collapse" : "Expand")
                   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                          minHeight: 60,
                          maxHeight: 60,
                          alignment: .center)
                   .foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                   .background(Color(.white))
           }).overlay(Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .background(LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white.opacity(0), .white.opacity(1)]),
                                   startPoint: .top,
                                   endPoint: .bottom))
                          .frame(height: 30)
                          .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.top] + 30 },
                alignment: .top)
```